# ubuntu16.04 Django1.11.15+Apache2.4+ptyhon2.7.12+mod_wsgi connection fail

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu-16.04

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName geo-lab
        <Directory "/bbgo/bbgo/bbgo">
                <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
                </Files>
         </Directory>

        Alias /static/admin /bbgo/bbgoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/
        <Directory "/bbgo/bbgoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        Alias /static/summernote /bbgo/bbgoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_summernote/static/summernote/
        <Directory "/bbgo/bbgoenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_summernote/static/summernote/">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        Alias /static /bbgo/bbgo/static
        <Directory "/bbgo/bbgo/static">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        Alias /upload /bbgo/bbgo/upload
        <Directory "/bbgo/bbgo/upload">
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

           WSGIDaemonProcess bbgo python-home=/bbgo/bbgoenv python-path=/bbgo/bbgo
           WSGIProcessGroup bbgo
           WSGIScriptAlias / /bbgo/bbgo/bbgo/wsgi.py


         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

i USED http in my 000-default.conf

```
.
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── VERSION
├── accounts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20180605_1409.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20180605_1409.pyc
│   │   ├── 0003_profile_alarm_paper.py
│   │   ├── 0003_profile_alarm_paper.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── aliases
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── bbgo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── apache
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── blogs
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20181114_1340.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20181114_1340.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── boards
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20180607_1648.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20180607_1648.pyc
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20181114_1340.py
│   │   ├── 0003_auto_20181114_1340.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── table.py
│   ├── table.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── core
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── api.pyc
│   ├── apiurls.py
│   ├── apiurls.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── context_processors.py
│   ├── context_processors.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── templatetags
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __init__.pyc
│   │   ├── alarm.py
│   │   ├── alarm.pyc
│   │   ├── alias.py
│   │   ├── alias.pyc
│   │   ├── blogtools.py
│   │   ├── blogtools.pyc
│   │   ├── boardtools.py
│   │   ├── boardtools.pyc
│   │   ├── bookmark.py
│   │   ├── bookmark.pyc
│   │   ├── category.py
│   │   ├── category.pyc
│   │   ├── censor.py
│   │   ├── censor.pyc
│   │   ├── comment.py
│   │   ├── comment.pyc
│   │   ├── context.py
│   │   ├── context.pyc
│   │   ├── datetime.py
│   │   ├── datetime.pyc
│   │   ├── like.py
│   │   ├── like.pyc
│   │   ├── link.py
│   │   ├── link.pyc
│   │   ├── menu.py
│   │   ├── menu.pyc
│   │   ├── navigator.py
│   │   ├── navigator.pyc
│   │   ├── pick.py
│   │   ├── pick.pyc
│   │   ├── range.py
│   │   ├── range.pyc
│   │   ├── reply.py
│   │   ├── reply.pyc
│   │   ├── sense.py
│   │   ├── sense.pyc
│   │   ├── spam.py
│   │   ├── spam.pyc
│   │   ├── status.py
│   │   ├── status.pyc
│   │   ├── tags.py
│   │   ├── tags.pyc
│   │   ├── team.py
│   │   ├── team.pyc
│   │   ├── team_reply.py
│   │   ├── team_reply.pyc
│   │   ├── terms.py
│   │   ├── terms.pyc
│   │   ├── user.py
│   │   └── user.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── utils.py
│   ├── utils.pyc
│   └── views.py
├── docs
│   ├── browserstack.png
│   └── secrets_sample.json
├── locale
│   ├── en
│   │   └── LC_MESSAGES
│   │       ├── django.mo
│   │       ├── django.po
│   │       ├── djangojs.mo
│   │       └── djangojs.po
│   └── ko
│       └── LC_MESSAGES
│           ├── django.mo
│           ├── django.po
│           ├── djangojs.mo
│           └── djangojs.po
├── manage.py
├── msgs
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20181114_1340.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20181114_1340.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── papers
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20181114_1340.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20181114_1340.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── portal
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── recipes
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── requirements.txt
├── runlocalserver.sh
├── secrets.json
├── spams
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css.map
│   │   ├── fonts.css
│   │   ├── haru-1.2.css
│   │   ├── monokai-sublime.min.css
│   │   ├── popup.css
│   │   ├── waitMe.css
│   │   └── xcode.min.css
│   ├── fonts
│   │   ├── NotoSansKR-Black.woff2
│   │   ├── NotoSansKR-Bold.woff2
│   │   ├── NotoSansKR-Light.woff2
│   │   ├── NotoSansKR-Medium.woff2
│   │   ├── NotoSansKR-Regular.woff2
│   │   └── NotoSansKR-Thin.woff2
│   ├── icons
│   │   ├── account30.png
│   │   ├── addphoto200.png
│   │   ├── alert24.gif
│   │   ├── alert24.png
│   │   ├── alert96.png
│   │   ├── apple-touch-icon.png
│   │   ├── arrowright18.png
│   │   ├── arrowright24.png
│   │   ├── attachment18.png
│   │   ├── back18.png
│   │   ├── captain14.png
│   │   ├── comment18.png
│   │   ├── community64.png
│   │   ├── customize64.png
│   │   ├── delete10.png
│   │   ├── delete24.png
│   │   ├── down48.png
│   │   ├── edit20.png
│   │   ├── edit24.png
│   │   ├── email24.png
│   │   ├── eye18.png
│   │   ├── facebook16.png
│   │   ├── facebook24.png
│   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── free64.png
│   │   ├── library64.png
│   │   ├── like24.png
│   │   ├── link18.png
│   │   ├── lock18.png
│   │   ├── message24.png
│   │   ├── niun18.png
│   │   ├── niun24.png
│   │   ├── noimage.png
│   │   ├── nomessage24.png
│   │   ├── not80.png
│   │   ├── paper64.png
│   │   ├── photo20.png
│   │   ├── power.png
│   │   ├── poweron.png
│   │   ├── renew18.png
│   │   ├── scrap16.png
│   │   ├── scrap24.png
│   │   ├── star28.png
│   │   ├── stared28.png
│   │   ├── thumbdown24.png
│   │   ├── thumbup24.png
│   │   ├── twitter16.png
│   │   ├── twitter24.png
│   │   ├── up48.png
│   │   ├── video20.png
│   │   └── watch18.png
│   ├── images
│   │   ├── side_banner_alias.png
│   │   ├── side_banner_bbgo.png
│   │   ├── side_banner_confluence.png
│   │   ├── side_banner_recipe.png
│   │   └── side_banner_vault.png
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── accounts
│   │   │   ├── alarm.js
│   │   │   ├── bookmarks.js
│   │   │   ├── deactivate.js
│   │   │   ├── edit_bookmarks.js
│   │   │   ├── idmenu.js
│   │   │   ├── member.js
│   │   │   ├── setting.js
│   │   │   ├── signup.js
│   │   │   ├── suspension.js
│   │   │   └── usersearch.js
│   │   ├── aliases
│   │   │   └── alias.js
│   │   ├── blogs
│   │   │   ├── blogs_comment.js
│   │   │   ├── blogs_edit.js
│   │   │   ├── blogs_list.js
│   │   │   ├── blogs_post.js
│   │   │   ├── dashboard.js
│   │   │   └── sidemenu.js
│   │   ├── boards
│   │   │   ├── boards_article.js
│   │   │   ├── boards_edit.js
│   │   │   ├── boards_list.js
│   │   │   ├── boards_reply.js
│   │   │   ├── dashboard.js
│   │   │   └── reply_list.js
│   │   ├── msgs
│   │   │   ├── conversation.js
│   │   │   ├── inbox.js
│   │   │   └── message.js
│   │   ├── papers
│   │   │   ├── papers.js
│   │   │   ├── papers_edit.js
│   │   │   ├── papers_inbox.js
│   │   │   └── papers_summary.js
│   │   ├── recipes
│   │   │   ├── category.js
│   │   │   └── recipes.js
│   │   ├── spams
│   │   │   └── spam.js
│   │   ├── teams
│   │   │   ├── edit_recruitment.js
│   │   │   ├── recruitment.js
│   │   │   ├── show_recruitment.js
│   │   │   ├── team.js
│   │   │   └── teams_reply.js
│   │   ├── thirdparty
│   │   │   ├── appear.min.js
│   │   │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
│   │   │   ├── easyNotify.js
│   │   │   ├── easyNotify.min.js
│   │   │   ├── highlight.js
│   │   │   ├── highlight.min.js
│   │   │   ├── highlightjs-line-numbers.min.js
│   │   │   ├── jquery-3.2.1.min.js
│   │   │   ├── jquery-ui-touch-punch.min.js
│   │   │   ├── jquery-ui.min.js
│   │   │   ├── jquery.mark.min.js
│   │   │   ├── toast.js
│   │   │   └── waitMe.min.js
│   │   └── vaults
│   │       ├── check_key.js
│   │       ├── edit_key.js
│   │       ├── new_key.js
│   │       └── vault.js
│   └── jsi18n
│       └── ko-KR
│           └── djangojs.js
├── teams
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── admin.pyc
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── forms.pyc
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20181114_1340.py
│   │   ├── 0002_auto_20181114_1340.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __init__.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── models.pyc
│   ├── table.py
│   ├── table.pyc
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── views.py
│   └── views.pyc
├── templates
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── 500.html
│   ├── haru
│   │   ├── accounts
│   │   │   ├── alarm_list.html
│   │   │   ├── dashboard_user.html
│   │   │   ├── deactivate_account.html
│   │   │   ├── edit_bookmarks.html
│   │   │   ├── edit_user_info.html
│   │   │   ├── join.html
│   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   ├── scrap.html
│   │   │   ├── setting.html
│   │   │   ├── show_delete_terms.html
│   │   │   ├── show_terms.html
│   │   │   ├── signup.html
│   │   │   └── user_info.html
│   │   ├── aliases
│   │   │   ├── dashboard.html
│   │   │   └── show_aliases.html
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── blogs
│   │   │   ├── dashboard.html
│   │   │   ├── dashboard_comment.html
│   │   │   ├── dashboard_post.html
│   │   │   ├── edit_post.html
│   │   │   ├── show_blogs.html
│   │   │   ├── show_comment.html
│   │   │   ├── show_post.html
│   │   │   └── show_tags.html
│   │   ├── boards
│   │   │   ├── dashboard.html
│   │   │   ├── dashboard_article.html
│   │   │   ├── dashboard_reply.html
│   │   │   ├── edit_article.html
│   │   │   ├── like_users.html
│   │   │   ├── search_reply.html
│   │   │   ├── show_article.html
│   │   │   ├── show_list.html
│   │   │   └── show_reply.html
│   │   ├── error.html
│   │   ├── error_response.html
│   │   ├── menu_banner.html
│   │   ├── menu_footer.html
│   │   ├── menu_main.html
│   │   ├── menu_mobile.html
│   │   ├── menu_setting.html
│   │   ├── menu_sub.html
│   │   ├── msgs
│   │   │   ├── conversation.html
│   │   │   ├── inbox.html
│   │   │   └── send_msg.html
│   │   ├── papers
│   │   │   ├── edit_paper.html
│   │   │   ├── paper_file.html
│   │   │   ├── show_inbox.html
│   │   │   ├── show_paper.html
│   │   │   ├── summary.html
│   │   │   └── user_list.html
│   │   ├── portal
│   │   │   └── bbgo.html
│   │   ├── recipes
│   │   │   ├── edit_category.html
│   │   │   ├── edit_recipe.html
│   │   │   ├── instruction.html
│   │   │   ├── show_category.html
│   │   │   └── show_recipes.html
│   │   ├── registration
│   │   │   ├── logged_out.html
│   │   │   ├── password_change_done.html
│   │   │   ├── password_change_form.html
│   │   │   ├── password_reset_complete.html
│   │   │   ├── password_reset_confirm.html
│   │   │   ├── password_reset_done.html
│   │   │   ├── password_reset_email.html
│   │   │   └── password_reset_form.html
│   │   ├── show_navigator.html
│   │   ├── show_sense.html
│   │   ├── spams
│   │   │   ├── show_ips.html
│   │   │   ├── show_words.html
│   │   │   └── spam_setting.html
│   │   ├── teams
│   │   │   ├── edit_recruitment.html
│   │   │   ├── recruitment.html
│   │   │   ├── show_recruitment.html
│   │   │   ├── show_team.html
│   │   │   └── show_team_reply.html
│   │   └── vaults
│   │       ├── check_key.html
│   │       ├── edit_key.html
│   │       ├── edit_vault.html
│   │       ├── new_key.html
│   │       └── show_vault.html
│   └── robots.txt
├── trans.sh
└── vaults
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── admin.py
    ├── admin.pyc
    ├── apps.py
    ├── forms.py
    ├── forms.pyc
    ├── migrations
    │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   ├── 0001_initial.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── __init__.pyc
    ├── models.py
    ├── models.pyc
    ├── tests.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── views.py
    └── views.pyc
```

in my project tree

```
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.773732 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4428:tid 140249052182400] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.773749 2018] [mpm_event:info] [pid 4428:tid 140249052182400] AH00490: Server built: 2018-06-07T19:43:03
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.773762 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4428:tid 140249052182400] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.773933 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4561:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Python home /bbgo/bbgoenv.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.773945 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4561:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Initializing Python.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.774491 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4562:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4562): Initializing Python.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.774792 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4563:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4563): Initializing Python.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.781233 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4561:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.781348 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4561:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Adding '/bbgo/bbgo' to path.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.789029 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4563:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4563): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.789124 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4562:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4562): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.846283 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4562:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4562): Destroying interpreters.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.846302 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4562:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4562): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.846368 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4563:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4563): Destroying interpreters.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.846387 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4563:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4563): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.848839 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4562:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4562): Terminating Python.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.849233 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4563:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4563): Terminating Python.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.851521 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4562:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4562): Python has shutdown.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.852066 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4563:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4563): Python has shutdown.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.861872 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4428:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Process 'bbgo' to be deregistered, as server is restarting or being shutdown.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.861899 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4428:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Process 'bbgo' has been deregistered and will no longer be monitored.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.861935 2018] [core:info] [pid 4428:tid 140249052182400] AH00096: removed PID file /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid (pid=4428)
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.861941 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4428:tid 140249052182400] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.872859 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4561:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Shutdown requested 'bbgo'.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.873029 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4561:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Stopping process 'bbgo'.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.873051 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4561:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Destroying interpreters.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.873060 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4561:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Cleanup interpreter ''.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.878141 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4561:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Terminating Python.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.881156 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4561:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Python has shutdown.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:04.881188 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4561:tid 140249052182400] mod_wsgi (pid=4561): Exiting process 'bbgo'.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.946189 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 4666:tid 140189576169344] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.11.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.946245 2018] [wsgi:warn] [pid 4666:tid 140189576169344] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.12.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.946999 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4669:tid 140189576169344] mod_wsgi (pid=4669): Starting process 'bbgo' with uid=33, gid=33 and threads=15.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.947350 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4669:tid 140189576169344] mod_wsgi (pid=4669): Python home /bbgo/bbgoenv.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.947368 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4669:tid 140189576169344] mod_wsgi (pid=4669): Initializing Python.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.947407 2018] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 4666:tid 140189576169344] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/2.7.12configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.947425 2018] [mpm_event:info] [pid 4666:tid 140189576169344] AH00490: Server built: 2018-06-07T19:43:03
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.947437 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4666:tid 140189576169344] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.947545 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4670:tid 140189576169344] mod_wsgi (pid=4670): Initializing Python.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.947838 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4671:tid 140189576169344] mod_wsgi (pid=4671): Initializing Python.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.958943 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4669:tid 140189576169344] mod_wsgi (pid=4669): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.959115 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4669:tid 140189576169344] mod_wsgi (pid=4669): Adding '/bbgo/bbgo' to path.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.959695 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4671:tid 140189576169344] mod_wsgi (pid=4671): Attach interpreter ''.
[Wed Nov 14 14:28:05.961189 2018] [wsgi:info] [pid 4670:tid 140189576169344] mod_wsgi (pid=4670): Attach interpreter ''.
```

in my Apache log

When I was in Django debugging mode, I found out that the home page was going well. However, it does not enter the local host if it is linked to an Apache. I don't know why.
https://gencode.me/boards/article/16/3/ 
It was built by referring to this homepage, but there is a problem with Apache linkage.I'd appreciate your help. I will give you the information you need.
My Django located in Bbgo/bbbgoenv.

Comment: What do you mean by "However, it does not enter the local host if it is linked to an Apache."?

Comment: yes right!! it is

Comment: You did not answer my question.